# How to remove elements from a JList passed as a parameter to a method?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

```
public static void removeItems(JList newMenuItemsList)  {
    DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) newMenuItemsList.getModel();
    listModel.removeAllElements();       
}
```

I get an excpetion when I run this code

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
     javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel
```

How can I overcome this.

Comment: Your JList doesn't appear to use a DefaultListModel. If you need it to do so, why not give it one?

Comment: By not assuming that a JList's model is of type DefaultListModel. Or by making this assumption only if you're sure it's a DefaultListModel, because you have set the model before in this JList, and it is of type DefaultListModel.

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will reduce the guess work and promote better answers to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you are creating the JList using an Array with code something like:

```
String[] numbers = { "1001", "1002", "1003" };
JList list1 = new JList<String>( numbers );
```

If you create a `JList` using an Array as a parameter then the `JList` creates a simple implementation of a `ListModel` for you. This model will be static and can't be changed. That is why you see the `JList$3` as the class name of the model.

If you want a dynamic `ListModel` then you need to use a dynamic model.

An easy way to do this is to use the `DefaultComboBoxModel`. It allows you to use an Array as you create the instance of the `DefaultComboBoxModel`.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(numbers);
JList list2 = new JList<String>( model );
```

If you want to use the `DefaultListModel`, then you will need to create the `DefaultListModel` and then load each item of the Array into the model separately.

```
DefaulListModel model2 = new DefaultListModel();
JList list2 = new JList<String>( model2 );

for (String number: numbers)
    model2.addElement( number );
```